# Java SQL Server 2012 Cannot open database error

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, tcp

I seem to be running into the error: `Cannot open database  requested by the login. The login failed.` when connecting my SQL Server database to a Java application written in netbeans.

I have read numerous articles and done the following:

- Allowed the 1433 port to the firewall under UDP and TCP
- Set SQL Server Configuration Manager TCP/IP ports to 1433
- Changed the server authentication in SQL Server Management Studio to mixed authentication
- Allowed remote connections in SQL Server Management Studio

My connection string is as follows:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;DatabaseName = SASS; IntegratedSecurity=true; Trusted_Connection=true;
```

and I am still getting the following error:

```
Cannot open database "SASS" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:894b97b9-54d6-47cc-afd7-1473a460c09d
```

After reading for 3 days straight, I am at my wits end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seemed to have figured out what was going on. I had changed my pc's settings and updated so many things, I must've broken something along the way.

Below are a set of instructions that I've worked out in the event that anyone else has problems with Java connections. This was done on a newly installed machine:

Connecting a SQL Server Database (2008 or 2012) to a Java Netbeans Application:

1. Install SQL Server Management Studio 2008 or 2012
2. Install SQL Server 
   a.  Name the Server Instance SQLExpress/SQLEXPRESS
   b.  Make sure that the server accepts mixed methods of authentication (SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode)
   c.  Give the System Administrator the password: admin
3. Install the latest JRE and JDKs
4. Install Netbeans
5. Create a test database in SQL Server Management Studio to test later
6. Update the firewall to accept the incoming and outgoing port 1434 for TCP AND UDP
7. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager

   a. Stop both the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) and SQL Server Browser services

   b. Open the Protocols for SQLEXPRESS under SQL Server Network Configuration and enable TCP/IP

   c. Enable all ports (ESPECIALLY IPAll) and set the ports to 1434

   d. Enable the services again (especially the SQL Server Browser)
8. Unzip sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu to C:\ drive
9. Copy and paste the DLL file from C:\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86 or C:\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64  (depending on whether you’re running a 64bit Java installation or 32bit – DO NOT COPY BOTH).
10. Copy and paste the DLL file into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
11. Add the sqljdbc driver to your Java Netbeans application

    a. Add the sqljdbc driver to the application library (right click  add)

    b. Under the Services tab, expand “Databases” and right click on “Drivers”

    c. Add the sqljdbc4 driver to the service (Right click  New Driver…)

    d. Make sure the connection string is similar to:
    jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS; database=[Database Name]; integratedSecurity = true;
    where localhost\SQLEXPRESS is changed to the server you are running your database from

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string indicates that you are using Integrated Security over a Trusted Connection.  This means that whatever user that is running your process that calls the database must have access to SQL Server and your individual database.  I recommend that you use mixed authentication in SQL with a named user.  Read more about it on MSDN SQL Server 2012 documentation:

[Create a Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

[Create a Database User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Then you can create a connection string like this:

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

[SQL Server Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to remove the error I was getting, but now I'm getting: `The server sqlexpress is not configured to listen with TCP/IP.` I've already enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server Config Manager.

Comment: There is a great tutorial on fixing this issue here: http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/