# Not able to access one database in SQL Server using Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2012

I have an SQL Server 2012 edition. I have two databases on this server. One of these databases named BANKTEST was restored from a backup a few months ago. I have recently restored another database named NEWBANK.

The following is the java program which I had written to access NEWBANK

```
package com.example.myproject.client;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectMSSQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;user=sa;password=sa123;Database=NEWBANk");
        System.out.println("test");
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
        String Sql = "select TOP 10 CodeType from D001002";
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("CodeType"));
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error which I have listed below

```
> Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "NEWBANK" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:69c57dd7-38b1-413c-b8ea-8d53824f74e1
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.myproject.client.ConnectMSSQL.main(ConnectMSSQL.java:13)
```

If I replace the name of the database with BANKTEST, I do not get any errors. Can someone advice me on this?

Regards

Sachin

Comment: check this link it may be helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974017/java-sql-server-2012-cannot-open-database-error

Comment: Hi, the point is that I am able to access one database within this sql server whereas I am not able to access the other database. Is there some setting in the database which I am missing. Unfortunately, the last time, I had done a restore, I had not done any changes in the database settings.

Answer (score 4):

The error shows that the username and password which you are using to login to your database `NEWBANK` is not valid or does not have the permision to access it.

You need to check your login details with your DBA and then try to login again. You can also check if you can access the database using the SQL Server Management Studio using the login credentails you are using in code.(*You will probably find the same error over there as well*)

You can also follow the steps given here: [SQL SERVER – FIX : ERROR : Cannot open database requested by the login.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/)

> Go to SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and select Properties

[image]

> In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the “User Mapping”
>   tab. Then, on the “User Mapping” tab, select the desired database –
>   especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On
>   the lower screen, check the role db_owner. Click OK.

[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul - thanks, I tried this but it does not work.

Comment: @sachinb:- Are you able to login through the SQL Server management studio?

Comment: Yes, Rahul. I can access the database through SQL server management studio. Also, I get a valid result, if I run a query on this database

Comment: @sachinb:- Try to add the location of "sqljdbc_auth.dll" in java.library.path

Comment: @sachinb:- Also if this specific to a particular database ie, NEWBANK  or every database?

Comment: This is specific to NEWBANK. I can access "BANKTEST" which is an earlier backup

Comment: @sachinb:- try to use this connetion string: `jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;instance=yourInstanceName;DatabaseName=NEWBANK;user=sa;password=sa123;integratedSecurity=true`

Comment: Tried the connection string, but, it does not work :-(

Comment: I did a slight variation on this. But this helped on the way!