# Java SQL Server 2014 Cannot open database error

Tags: sql-server, eclipse

*(not same case as: [Java SQL Server 2012 Cannot open database error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974017/java-sql-server-2012-cannot-open-database-error?rq=1))*

I have an environment running iReport 4.7.1, and I connect it to SQL Server 2014 using the driver from JBoss 6 lib folder: sqljdbc4.jar.

This same driver, on the same porto (1433) is not working to connect Eclipse Mars2 64bits to SQL Server.

When creating the driver I did select "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 JDBC Driver" (the most recent on the list), but I hope this is only a name, as I selected the jar I'm successfully using to connect iReport (sqljdbc4.jar).

I got

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database
>   "databaseName=MY_DB" requested by the login. The login failed.

My Connection URL is the same that's working on iReport:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=databaseName=MY_DB
```

Also, Eclipse is running under Java 8, and iReport under Java 6, but I believe this is not the issue.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection URL sets "databaseName=" twice. Try changing it to:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MY_DB
```