# Hpw can I Connect Remote Desktop Computer's database to normal computers Neatbeans?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans, sqlconnection

I can't connect my remote database to my NetBeans program. First I opened New Connecton Wizard from Services -> Drivers -> New Driver.

Then I get this error

> " Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://(host):(portnumber);
>   databaseName=.... using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
>   (Cannot open database "...." requested by the login.
>
> The login failed. ClientConnectionId---------------------------)
>   "

How can I fix this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot open database "...." requested by the login. The login failed

It means that database listed in your connection string under `databaseName=` either does not exist/is not online, or your login is not mapped to it.

To fix this issue please insure that requested database is `online` and your login is mapped to it, or change `databaseName=` to `master`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check that:
 1. You opened SQL Server Configuration Manager
 2. You added the sqljdbc driver to the application library

You can read this post: [Java SQL Server 2012 Cannot open database error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974017/java-sql-server-2012-cannot-open-database-error)